# How to disable the key 'V' in VI Editing Mode against bash

Tags: bash, readline

As we know, after changed the Readline mode to vi by command `set -o vi` and `set editing-mod vi`, press the key <kbd>v</kbd> can into an temp file to edit command ([here](http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.txt) more details). I want to disable that function.

I tried to re-map <kbd>v</kbd> in ~/.inputrc likes:

```
"v":
```

but the **character v** cannot be inputed, even if at the **insert mode** (`vim` cannot be inputed also. =.=!).

How should I do? And how to re-map the shortcut-keys and do **NOT** effect the input-mode against VI Editing Mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the binding only for the correct mode (`vi-command`, not `vi-insert`), and you need to provide a right-hand-side to the rule:

```
set keymap vi-command                                                                            
v: ""
```

Comment: Nop.. if input `v: ""`, char v cannot be input in **insert mode**, and command **v** still can open the vim to edit the command.

Comment: Did you add both lines, in that order? If yes, is there anything else in your `.inputrc`, and if there is, can you add the whole thing to your question?

Comment: yes!! it works!! I added the both line in *.inputrc*, and delete `set keymap vi-insert`, then, it works!! Thanks!!

Comment: I think I got it. I will set the 'v' to idle in **command** mode. So I should use `vi-command` as keymap mode. Am I right?

Comment: You can have custom mappings for all modes in the same file. The important thing to know is that lines are processed strictly in order: after a `set keymap` line, all mappings apply to that mode, until the next `set keymap` line, and any mappings _after_ that will apply to the new mode.

Comment: I have a problem. I set the **ctrl+p** is show previous history (`"\C-P": previous-history`) before, and the keymap is **vi-insert**. Then the ctrl+p will show the previous history at insert mode. But, this shortcut doesn't work after I set the `keymap vi-command`. What should I do to let the **Ctrl+p** works in **insert mord** and the **keymap** still is **vi-command**? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, I figure that out, :). different modes can be existed in the same .inputrc at the same time. So this problem has fixed!